# Disable UISlider interaction temporarily

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit, uislider

I'm trying to run `performSegue:` when a `UISlider` reaches a given progress, so I want it execute only once. Is it possible to disable the sliding interaction instantly?

I've already tried using `resignFirstResponder`, setting `enabled` and `userInteractionEnabled` to `false` and back to `true`, and iterating through the associated gesture recognizers disabling and enabling them again. None of this alternatives produced the desired effect.

I want the control to remain active for future events but to stop the interaction of the current event. Disabling user interaction and living it disabled does not solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use a boolean instance variable, `triggered`.  Check if it's true when you're responding to a `ValueChanged` event and bail out if it is.  Set the variable to true otherwise and perform your segue.  Set the variable back to false on the `TouchCancel` event.

Comment: The interaction doesn't stop, the user can still slide the slider

Answer (score 0):

As UISlider inherits from UIControl, setting the Boolean value of the control to YES or NO - WILL toggle its enabled state. If disabled, the slider will look opaque.
Also as UIControl inherits from UIView, setting the Boolean value of userInteractionEnabled - WILL toggle whether user events are ignored or not. If disabled, the slider will look normal but does not move etc.

HOWEVER - if you have started using the slider and its use selects a method and in that method you use .enabled or .userInteractionEnabled, then it continuous to fire until you let go, i.e. repeatedly calls that method. Once you let go, your control setting will work.
To avoid multiple execution of the called method, you can at the beginning of that method query the state of a flag and if set yes, return out of that method. Immediately after the query, set a Bool flag to yes and of course - somewhere in your code where it makes sense (when the method has served its purpose) set the flag to no again (or maybe setting the continuous property to NO already helps):

```
    -(void)methodSelectedBySlider
    {
    if (_inSelectedMethodFlag==YES) {
       return;
    }

   _inSelectedMethodFlag = YES;
```